# How can i get the summation or the total of extracted values from neo4j path? i can't just use directly sum function

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

[image]

--- sum(extract(b IN nodes(p)| b.userReputation)) AS UserRep ---

that's the value i want to find thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way to perform summation on the items in a collection is to use an `UNWIND` clause. For example, you can replace your original `RETURN` clause with:

```
UNWIND NODES(p) AS nd
RETURN p, SUM(nd.userReputation) AS userRep;
```

NOTE: the above `RETURN` clause also returns `p`, so that the [aggregation](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/aggregation/) function `SUM` aggregates over the appropriate "key value". You would probably want to return `p` anyway, so that you know the path that each sum is for.

Comment: This will works, but the query plan is not the same as mine. Due to unwind + aggregation, you have an `eageraggregation` that is less performant than just a projection. But it's a little more readable.

Answer (score 1):

`sum` is an aggregation function, so it makes the job on the resultset, not on an array.
What you want to do is a `reduce`.

Can you try this : `reduce(s = 0, x IN extract(b IN nodes(p)| coalesce(b.userReputation, 0)) | s + x) AS UserRep`

Cheers

Comment: @logisma, i don't know somehow your solution to my question is not working anymore! can't you re-check again?